# Google Script: JDBC prepareStatement Failing

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, prepared-statement

Despite reading other posts here, and via Google, I still can't determine what is wrong with my prepareStatement:

```
function sqlInsertEntities(){
  const conn = sqlGetConnection();
  if (!conn) { return; }  // Check conn is successful first!
  ...
  var sqlData = filteredData.map(arrangeCols); // map to same column order as in MySQL
  Logger.log(sqlData); 
    /** As expected, returns:
     * [ [1.0, SSLPA, Sietel Ltd, 7.0, ASX:SSLPA], [1.0, WHFPA, Whitefield Ltd, 7.0, ASX:WHFPA], 
     * [4.0, XTL, S&P/ASX 20, 7.0, INDEXASX:XTL], [4.0, XFL, S&P/ASX 50, 7.0, INDEXASX:XFL] ]
     */
  try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
      'INSERT INTO ' + 
      'entity (entity_type_id, entity_code, entity_name, exchange_id, googlefinance_ticker) ' + 
      'values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?),' +
      ' true');                     // Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ???
    for (var i=0; i<sqlData; i++) {
      stmt.setInt(   1, sqlData[i][0]);
      stmt.setString(2, sqlData[i][1]);
      stmt.setString(3, sqlData[i][2]);
      stmt.setInt(   4, sqlData[i][3]);
      stmt.setString(5, sqlData[i][4]);
      stmt.addBatch();
    }
    var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
    Logger.log(batch.length); 
    // Returns 0.  The INSERT is not happening, but no Error returned?
  } 
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + e + ' : ' + e.getMessage() + '\nline: ' + e.lineNumber);
    Browser.msgBox('Error',e + ' : ' + e.getMessage() + '\\nline: ' + e.lineNumber, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
  finally {
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

I also tried removing the `true` param from prepareStatement since I'm unsure how to get the autoGeneratedKeys back yet, but that made no difference.

This is my first attempt at using MySQL with Google Sheets, so any advice or corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Nope, none at all !

Answer (score 0):

Not really an *answer*, but as a work-around, I've resorted to preparing the complete SQL statement, and then using createStatement:

```
  // Prepare SQL
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + 
      'entity (entity_type_id, entity_code, entity_name, exchange_id, googlefinance_ticker) ' + 
      'values ';
    var rows = sqlData.length;
    var cols = sqlData[0].length;
    for (var row=0; row<rows; row++) {
      sql = sql + '('
      for (col=0; col<cols; col++) {
        if ( isNaN( sqlData[row][col] ) && sqlData[row][col].length > 0 ) {
          // Need to encapsulate strings
          sql = sql + "'" + sqlData[row][col].toString() + "'";
        } else {
          sql = sql + sqlData[row][col];
        }
        if ( col != cols-1 ) { sql = sql + ','; }
      }
      sql = sql + '),';
    }
    sql = sql.substr(0,sql.length-1);
    // Logger.log(sql);
  //

  // Execute SQL
    try {
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
      var response = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);  // Nb: executeQuery is only for SELECT statements
      Logger.log(response);
    } 
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error: ' + e + '\nline: ' + e.lineNumber);
      Browser.msgBox('Error',e + '\\nline: ' + e.lineNumber, Browser.Buttons.OK);
    }
    finally {
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }
  //
```

Still haven't found out why prepareStatement doesn't work in Google script, but at least this works.